# Finitely number natural $n$ such that $2^{n}=xy-1$ with $x,y$ primes number and $x\not=y$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> If $x\not=y$ with $x,y$ primes number. Are there finitely many $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that
> $2^n=xy-1$?

Comment: So you're assessing how often $2^n+1$ is a [semiprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprime) , finitely often or infinitely. I'd expect the latter.

Comment: What is the origin of your question? I'm pretty sure this is an open problem.

Comment: @Joffan The word semiprime allows the two primes to be equal. In this post the OP specify $x\ne y$

Comment: @АлександрПальма When you are asking about a problem that invented yourself and you don't know if it has a solution, you should warn about that. Otherwise other users could waste a lot of time trying to solve an open problem.

Comment: @jjagmath Since $2^n + 1$ is a square only once, the restriction $x \neq y$ doesn't influence whether there are infinitely many or only finitely many.

Comment: @jjagmath My understanding of semiprime is that the two primes are distinct. There may be variations in usage of course. For clarity, I meant square-free semiprimes.

Comment: I think the usual Fermat business shows that for this to work we need $n$ to be of the form $n=2^ab$ where $b$ is either $1$ or an odd prime. This feels like a very difficult problem though.

Comment: @jjagmath Yes, you are right. Anyway I think this problem should have been asked in MO only I did not know the depth of the problem initially, then I tried to delete my post but since there is already an answer the MSE system does not allow me to delete. On the other hand, the problem is very interesting but it seems very difficult.

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:* They are the sequence [A092559](https://oeis.org/A092559) of integers $n$, such that $2^n+1$ is semiprime.

It starts with

$$
n=3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 12, 13, 17, 19, 20, 23, 28, 31, 32, 40, 43, 61, 64,\cdots
$$

It looks like that there are infinitely many such numbers, but I am not aware of a proof.

Comment: That's not the sequence. For $n=3$ we have $2^3+1 = 3^2$, so we would have $x=y=3$, but the OP specify in the question that $x\ne y$. The right sequence is [A073936](https://oeis.org/A073936)

Comment: @jjagmath True, but $9$ is the only square of the form $2^n+1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $n=2k+1$ , then we can write:

$2^n+1=(2+1)(2^{n-1}-2^{n-2}+ \cdot\cdot\cdot+1)$

So x or y can always be equal to  3. Since n is odd the number of terms of polynomial is odd and can not have factor 3 but itself can be prime.For example for n=5 we get:

$xy=32+1=33=3\times 11$

Or for n=7 we get:

$xy=2^7+1=129=3\times 43$

And so on.